# 4 dimensional matrix

Tags: matlab

I need to use 4 dimensional matrix as an accumulator for voting 4 parameters. every parameters vary in the range of 1~300. for that, I define Acc = zeros(300,300,300,300) in MATLAB. and somewhere for example, I used:

```
 Acc(4,10,120,78)=Acc(4,10,120,78)+1
```

however, MATLAB says some error happened because of memory limitation.

```
??? Error using ==> zeros
 Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

---

in the below, you can see a part of my code:

```
I = imread('image.bmp'); %I is logical 300x300 image.
Acc = zeros(100,100,100,100);
for i = 1:300
for j = 1:300
    if I(i,j)==1
        for x0 = 3:3:300
            for y0 = 3:3:300
                for a = 3:3:300
                        b = abs(j-y0)/sqrt(1-((i-x0)^2) / (a^2));
                        b1=floor(b/3);
                        if b1==0
                            b1=1;
                        end
                        a1=ceil(a/3);
                        Acc(x0/3,y0/3,a1,b1) = Acc(x0/3,y0/3,a1,b1)+1;                        
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

Comment: 300*300*300*300 = 8,100,000,000 * sizeof(double) = new supercomputer

Comment: on a more serious note, i don't know what you're doing to your data, but you may want to contemplate using a sparse matrix

Comment: Yes, I know my definition about zero matrix is mistake. I want to know the solution.

Comment: One shortcut to speed up your solution to this hough transform is to use multiscale processing.  First use a coarse histogram with large bins (perhaps only 10 settings for each (x0,y0,a,b) and accumulate evidence within each.  If any bin accumulates enough evidence to support an elipse, perform a finer grained histogram by refining those bins.

Comment: @BlessedKey, so you mean at first I use for example:

`for x0 = 3:10:300`

`for y0 = 3:10:300`

`for a = 3:10:300`

`...`

`Acc(x0/10,y0/10,a/10,b1) = Acc(x0/10,y0/10,a/10,b1)+1;`

after voting and using threshold, I will find some bins which offer inaccurate x0,y0,a,b. after that, what should I do to find accurate coordinates?

Comment: Then for each bin which passes the threshold of support, you will perform a more refined search.  If AccCoarse(h,i,j,k) passes, then perform the same operation, but using x0 = h-5:1:h+1  and accumulating AccFine(x0,y0,a1,b1).

Comment: Good idea. I hope I can implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: see lambdageek for the exact same answer with a bit more elegance.

The other answers are helping to guide you to use a sparse mat instead of your current dense solution.  This is made a little more difficult since current matlab doesn't support N-dimensional sparse arrays.  One implementation to do this is

replace

```
 zeros(100,100,100,100)
```

with

```
sparse(100*100*100*100,1)
```

this will store all your counts in a sparse array, as long as most remain zero, you will be ok for memory.

then to access this data, instead of:

```
 Acc(h,i,j,k)=Acc(h,i,j,k)+1
```

use:

```
 index = h+100*i+100*100*j+100*100*100*k
 Acc(index,1)=Acc(index,1)+1
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I implemented your solution. it worked without any memory issues. however, the process had been done very slow, which I had to terminate it in the middle of process. is it usual in this case that the process done long time?

Comment: well, you have a pretty large nested loop here.  For every pixel (100x100 = 10K pixels), for every setting of {x0,y0,a} (100x100x100 = 1M settings), increment a portion of of Acc.  The system must run 10 Billion loops.  There is probably a faster shortcut to compute Acc(h,i,j,k) as a transform on Img(x,y) when requested, rather than precomputing all values.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rasman mentioned, you probably want to use a sparse representation of the matrix Acc.

Unfortunately, the `sparse` function is geared toward 2D matrices, not arbitrary n-D.

But that's ok, because we can take advantage of `sub2ind` and *linear indexing* to go back and forth to 4D.

```
Dims = [300, 300, 300, 300];   % it will be a 300 by 300 by 300 by 300 matrix
Acc = sparse([], [], [], prod(Dims), 1, ExpectedNumElts);
```

Here `ExpectedNumElts` should be some number like 30 or 9000 or however many non-zero elements you expect for the matrix `Acc` to have.  We notionally think of `Acc` as a matrix, but actually it will be a vector.  But that's okay, we can use `sub2ind` to convert 4D coordinates into linear indices into the vector:

```
ind = sub2ind(Dims, 4, 10, 120, 78);
Acc(ind) = Acc(ind) + 1;
```

You may also find the functions `find`, `nnz`, `spy`, and `spfun` helpful.

Answer (score 0):

See [Avoiding 'Out of Memory' Errors](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1107.html)

Your statement would require more than 4 GB of RAM (Around 16 Gigs, to be specific).

> Solutions to 'Out of Memory' problems
>   fall into two main categories:
>
> - Maximizing the memory available to
>     MATLAB (i.e., removing or increasing
>     limits) on your system via operating
>     system selection and system
>     configuration. These usually have the
>     greatest overall applicability but are
>     potentially the most disruptive (e.g.
>     using a different operating system).
>     These techniques are covered in the
>     first two sections of this document.
> - Minimizing the memory used by MATLAB
>     by making your code more memory
>     efficient.  These are all algorithm
>     and application specific and therefore
>     are less broadly applicable. These
>     techniques are covered in later
>     sections of this document.

In your case later seems to be the solution - try reducing the amount of memory used / required.

Comment: Thank you for your notification.
but in this page, I couldn't find appropriate solution about my issue.

Comment: @Ata - it does, you'll have to reduce the memory usage or move on to a machine that has sufficient memory. How exactly to do that is a separate question and specific to your scenario.

Comment: @Ata Also - you don't exactly need a super computer (it needs around 16GB of ram), but a 64 bit system with over 16 gigs of ram (read 32 GB)

Comment: Actually its really not a complicated project. it's about ellipse detection using hough transform. I think there are some other ways which do not need to change system configurations.